# Логические задачи с использованием двоичной системы

Tags: математика, логика

кто-нибудь знает логические задачи которые решаються с использованием двоичной системы на подоби этой: https://thecode.media/binary-mouse/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая [страница гугла](https://acmp.ru/article.asp?id_text=847).

И на (ссылка удалена, так как сломана).

Comment: фу, фу, фу
кто же в гугле ищет :) Это моветон

Comment: @zhihar Ну все же иногда стоит попробовать глянуть там, а потом уже и где-то спрашивать) а так да, сайты с олимпиадными задачами будут получше для данной темы

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано: _являются всего лишь ссылкой на другой сайт_. Это сообщение, пожалуйста, или поправте, или удалите.

Answer (score 2):

https://problems.ru/view_by_subject_new.php?parent=102

ищите - тут олимпиадные задачи на разные системы счисления: двоичные, троичные и т.д.

соответственно указаны книжки из которых данные задачи взяты, так что можете еще и по этим книжкам пройтись